# npm ERR! code ENOENT installation error ionic cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I tried to install ionic and cordova (like many times before - without any problem) and it hadn't worked.
There's always this:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-d5384ff1
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
```

I tried several node.js versions and npm cache clean. But sadly nothing worked out.

Here are some lines from the npm-debug.log:

```
    72036 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js',
72036 silly gunzTarPerm   420,
72036 silly gunzTarPerm   438 ]
72037 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/package.json
72038 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/package.json',
72038 silly gunzTarPerm   420,
72038 silly gunzTarPerm   438 ]





81575 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
81576 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
81577 error node v6.9.1
81578 error npm  v3.10.8
81579 error path C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-d5384ff1
81580 error code ENOENT
81581 error errno -4058
81582 error syscall rename
81583 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-d5384ff1' -> 'C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
81584 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-d5384ff1' -> 'C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
81584 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
81584 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
81585 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Have anyone an idea what might be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if that folder exists C:\Users\Bastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ ? Try running it `cmd` in Admin mode (if not already) and see if its related to security issue.

Comment: yes, the folder exists (contains subfolders: cordova, firebase-tools, ionic). cmd in admin mode brings no difference

Comment: what is your nodejs/npm version and how did you install it

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question! I think it's the cache problem. I delete the 'C:\Users\Username.cordova' directory, and go to 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\', I delete the cordova directory. Then run "npm install -g cordova" again.It works for me! I hope it can help!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error. Seems like there is some version mismatch issue. even if we try installing the latest version for node and npm, npm intsall cordova fails giving error 4058. so its better to start afresh.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm cache clean
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```

This fixed my issue.